# Pass folder between builds - GitLab CI with Docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to have a separate docker container that build's my app, and when it finishes, it passes a 'dist' catalog to second container, which is deployed.

I tried using the artifacts and "volume" instruction, but it seems not to work. Anybody nows any work-around or solution?

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build
  - push
  - deploy


build_app:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./deployment/build.sh
  tags:
    - shell
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - /dist

push_app:
  stage: push
  script:
    - ./deployment/push.sh
  tags:
   - shell
  dependencies:
  - build_app

deploy_app:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./deployment/deploy.sh
  tags:
    - shell
```

**build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Building application"

docker build -t build:latest -f "deployment/build.docker" .
```

**build.docker**

```
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app/

WORKDIR /app

//code that creates /dist folder

VOLUME ["/app/dist"]
```

**push.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
docker build -t push:latest -f "deployment/push.docker" .

#and other stuff here
```

**push.docker**

```
// the first catalog is not there
ADD /app/dist /web
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [caching](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache):

> cache is used to specify a list of files and directories which should be cached between builds.

So you would define something like this in the **root** of your `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
cache:
  untracked: true
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
  paths:
    - dist/

build_app: ...
```

The `dist/` will then be cached among all builds.

Comment: `Step 3 : ADD /dist /web
lstat dist: no such file or directory
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1` Sadly, it's not working, and yes, this is what i was looking for

Comment: I am using cache for both Java (mvn) and NodeJs projects, I cannot really say why it isn't working for you. Try to strip your CI script to a minimum with 2 stages: one stage to fill up cache (`mkdir dist && touch dist/test.txt`) and another stage that checks if cache is there (`cat dist/test.txt`).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're not using the VOLUME command correctly in **build.docker**. If you boot build:latest image, the contents of /app/dist are copied to the container directory on the host file system. That is not equal to your current working directory.

Here's a fixed version:

**build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Building application"

docker build -t build:latest -f "deployment/build.docker" .

# Remove old dist directory
rm -rf ${PWD}/dist

# Here we boot the image, make a directory on the host system ${PWD}/dist and mount it into the container.
# After that we copy the files from /app/dist to the host system /dist
docker run -i -v ${PWD}/dist:/dist -w /dist -u $(id -u) \
    build:latest sh cp /app/dist /dist
```

**push.docker**

```
// the first catalog is not there
COPY /dist /web
```

Comment: `sh: 0: Can't open cp
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
` Something's wrong